# How do I display non-scientific formatted values on a JLabel and JTextField?

Tags: java, jlabel, scientific-notation

I have a string value that could contain a double, integer, ascii or byte value and I put that value into a JLabel.  I would like for the double and long values to be in the form of `4000000000000` instead of the java JLabel default printing style of `4.0E12`.  Now I know what data type is in the string but I don't know how to make the JLabel display only non-scientific forms for the double and integer values.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
String str = value; // string that holds the value

switch (var) // var that says which data type my str is
{
  case LONG:
  //convert my string from scientific to non-scientific here
  break;
  case DOUBLE:
  //convert my string from scientific to non-scientific here
  break;
  case ASCII:
  //do nothing
  break;
  ...
}

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText(str); //Want this to be in non-scientific form
```

but this method still only prints the scientific form.

Edit:

My conversion looks like:

```
str = new DecimalFormat("#0.###").format(str);
```

also yes it is a long value, i left out some of the data type variables for clearity.
I dont know if this will work for every case though even if i do get it working.  I need it to work for integer, long, xtended, double and float.

Comment: Sounds like your conversion is incorrect. Can you provide the code for how you do the conversion?  The JLabel will only print the text you give it. If the text is wrong, you are giving it the wrong text.  BTW, You cannot have an `int` value that big, do you mean a `long`?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I've provided the additional code along with the int to long explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using a different JLabel because it doesn't do any conversion by default

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel();
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.###");
label.setText(df.format(4e12));
frame.add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Displays a window with

```
4000000000000
```

---

I just get the following with that conversion

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.###");
System.out.println(df.format(400000000));
System.out.println(df.format(4000000000000L));
System.out.println(df.format(4e12f));
System.out.println(df.format(4e12));
```

prints

```
400000000
4000000000000
3999999983616   <- due to float rounding error.
4000000000000
```

Comment: Yea this is the right way to do it, I actually had another but that was causing it to print the wrong values.  Thanks!